# How to save data in json format?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, real-time

I created a program that receives data from four channels.
This is the type of data. 
( 0.499147;0.499147;0.499147;0.499147; )
(Separated by ';') Data can be read every interval set up to 100 times.
So I want to save the received data in JSON format.
I wrote the following code but could not save it in JSON format.

```
port.on('data',function(devicevalue){
arrayvalue = devicevalue.toString();
eachvalue = arrayvalue.split(';');

ch0value = eachvalue[0];
ch1value = eachvalue[1];
ch2value = eachvalue[2];
ch3value = eachvalue[3];

var json_data = 
        {
        index : i ,
        ch0value : eachvalue[0],
        ch1value : eachvalue[1],
        ch2value : eachvalue[2],
        ch3value : eachvalue[3],
        };
```

Later if i write this code

```
   jsonfile.writeFile(file,json_data,{flag: 'a', spaces: 2},function(err){
        console.error(err)
   });
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMc5M.png][https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMc5M.png]

If i write this instead of the above

```
    var objjson = JSON.stringify(json_data);
    jsonfile.writeFile(file,objjson,{flag: 'a', spaces: 2},function(err){
    console.error(err)
    });
```

[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ldPG.png][https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ldPG.png]

If I want this form, how do I write the code?

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEr3e.png][https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEr3e.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
var results = [];
var i = 0;
port.on('data', function(devicevalue) {
  var newElement = {
    index: i,
    ch0value: eachvalue[0],
    ch1value: eachvalue[1],
    ch2value: eachvalue[2],
    ch3value: eachvalue[3],
    ch4value: eachvalue[4]
  };
  results.push(newElement);
  i++;
});

port.on('close', function(code, signal) {
  jsonfile.writeFile(file,results,{flag: 'a', spaces: 2}, console.log);
});
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you very much for your help :))

Answer (score 0):

Try using toJS().

example: var.toJS();

You can also try toJSON. Same concept, but toJS returns a deeply copied version of the object.